# Android não reconhece parse.parse.initialize

Tags: java, android, api, parse

Estou no meu primeiro projeto com Android consumindo a API parse.
Segui à risca o tutorial e sempre obtenho o mesmo erro:

> could not find method com.parse.Parse.initialize

Eu utilizo ADT com SDK Tools atualizados.

Comment: Já passei por este erro certa vez, por acaso ele vem seguido de: referenced from method biz.rightshift.parsepush.RegisterFunction.call ?

Comment: Não, não vem seguido desse erro, Junior.

Comment: Mas parece que ele não encontra a classe...

Comment: Coloque o código e/ou o StackTrace pra facilitar a resposta.